# Seeking shapefiles for Marshlands, swampy areas in UK?

Tags: data, united-kingdom, waterways

Can anyone point me in the direction of shapefile data for all the coastal and inland areas of saltmarsh, wetland and inland marshes for the United Kingdom, including Isle of Man?

OS Open Data does not show any wetland/marshy ground on any of it's products!

Comment: If you seek open data then I think the best place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

**Ramsar** (named after a city in Iran where convention was signed in 1971) is the key word you are looking for (though not obvious)

For the United Kingdom you need to download shapefiles from these locations

For **England**
Natural England https://naturalengland-defra.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/ramsar-england

For **Wales**
http://lle.gov.wales/Catalogue/Item/ProtectedSitesRamsarWetlandsOfInternationalImportance/?lang=en

For **Scotland**
https://gateway.snh.gov.uk/natural-spaces/dataset.jsp?dsid=RAMSAR

For **Northen Ireland**
https://www.opendatani.gov.uk/dataset/ramsar-sites

For UK there is also the **JNCC**

Further sites are listed at the Joint Nature Conservation Committee (JNCC)

http://jncc.defra.gov.uk/page-1389

Note:
**OS VectorMap® District** files from (Great Britain (not UK) Coverage Only))
https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html

Have the following layers

Shrub and Marsh,Shrub and Marsh and Heath, Heathland and Marsh,Unimproved Grass and Sand, Marsh,Marsh and Unimproved Grass,Reeds